# Basic asynchronous confusion: Unsure how to synchronize these commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

My goal is to process elements of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` synchronously, even though they are each passed into an asynchronous function.

I want to get the values at the end in my `output` object and do something with it, but the `console.log` is running before the command before it finishes.

How do I change my code to wait for `runCmd` to finish before the final `console.log`?

Here's the script:

```
let nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

let asyncCommand = async function(cmd){
  let rInt = await Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
  for(let ii = 0; ii < rInt; await ii++){}
  return cmd;
}

let runCmd = function(num, remaining, output){
  console.log(output);

  return Promise.resolve(
    asyncCommand(num)
  ).then( 
    resolvedValue => {
      output.push(resolvedValue);
      if( remaining.length > 0 ){
    let next = remaining[0];
    let after = remaining.slice(1)
    return runCmd(next,after,output)
      }else{
    return output;
      }
    }
  )
}

let output = [];
runCmd(nums[0], nums.slice(1),output)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: `runCmd(nums[0], nums.slice(1),output).then(x => console.log(output));`

Comment: Using await for Math.floor sure doesn't make much sense, nor does `await ii++`

Comment: Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/z4ex2gv9/

Comment: @charlietfl nor does the empty loop.

Comment: This makes no sense. Nothing in your code is actually asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have completely understood your asyncCommand method, but I am answering assuming that it is correct.

The problem is that the asyncCommand is async, so the best way to call it is with an `await`, and save the result in a variable like this: `const result = await asyncCommand`.
This way you can ensure that the code below this line is executed only when the asyncCommand has finished.

As we want to use `await`, the runCmd method should be turned into an `async` function, and so it will return a Promise that has to be awaited (with `await` or `.then()` before consoling.log the result. This way, the final code for me would look something like this:

```
async function runCmd(num, remaining, output) {
  console.log(output);

  const resolvedValue = await asyncCommand(num)
  output.push(resolvedValue);
  
  if( remaining.length > 0 ){
    let next = remaining[0];
    let after = remaining.slice(1)
    return runCmd(next,after,output)
  } else {
    return output;
  }
}

let output = [];
runCmd(nums[0], nums.slice(1),output).then(_ => console.log(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion here, just use a good-old for loop:

```
let runCmd = async (nums) => {
  let output = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < remaining.length; i++) {
    output.push(await asyncCommand(nums[i]));
  }
  return output;
}

runCmd(nums)
```